# Как найти уникальные данные из 2 столбцов разных таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть 2 таблицы и в каждой есть столбец с id.
Как вывести данные с 1 таблицы столбца id которых нету в 2 таблице столбца id.
UNION выводит уникальные данные с 2 таблиц.

Comment: Оптимальный ответ зависит от статистики данных и существующих индексов. Либо это будет `LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL`, либо `WHERE NOT EXISTS`. Второе вероятнее...

Answer (score 0):

Решение нашлось в виде LEFT JOIN

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).